# Getting joined data from strongloop/loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

How can I get data from two joined tables? 
Suppose, there are two models called Category (CategoryId, CategoryName) and Product(ProductId, ProductName, CategoryId), Is there a way to get a result like:(ProductId, ProductName, CategoryId, CategoryName)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a relation between your Category model and your Product model. A Category *hasMany* Products and each Product *belongsTo* a Category. So your model json files should be something like

Category:

```
{
  "name":"Category",
  "properties":{
    "CategoryId": {
      "type":"Number",
      "id":1
    },
    "CategoryName":{
      "type":"String"
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "products": {
      "type":"hasMany",
      "model":"Product",
      "foreignKey":"CategoryId"
    }
  }
}
```

Product

```
{
  "name":"Product",
  "properties":{
    "ProductId: {
      "type":"Number",
      "id":1
    },
    "ProductName":{
      "type":"String"
    },
    "CategoryId": {
      "type":"Number"
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "category": {
      "type":"belongsTo",
      "model":"Category",
      "foreignKey":"CategoryId"
    }
  }
}
```

Of course these json definitions must be completed with the corresponding options and datasource properties, which only you do know.

The *relation* between those two models will add endpoints to loopback explorer so you can query for products in a certan category:

```
GET /api/Categorys/:id_category/products
```

of the category to which a product belongs

```
GET /api/Products/:id_product/category
```

Please note that, unless you specify a plural option for *Category*, its plural will be *Categorys*. This is not a typo.

Finally, if you want to query for a product and its category, you would use the *include* filter

```
GET /api/Products/:id_product?filter[include]=category
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So this also means that if you want joined data, a relationship is must.

Comment: Kind of. You could declare a custom remote method for Product which, for each result, made a call to Category.find and extended the product properties with its Category. But this relation substitute would be inneficient and probably overkill for common use cases.

Comment: This common loopback model technique unfortunately doesn't work when you have multiple foreign keys!!!

Comment: @kensai how so? You mean entities that belong to more than one entity? I have that use case and it works. Perhaps I can help you track down what's stopping yours from working

Comment: [loopback issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2080) is describing the issue, you can't have "foreignKey":["id1","id2"] definition in place in the moment. The only technique I know about how to override it is to use custom SQL statements. But welcome any model-driven solution.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you meant entites that are just bridges between other two, so they belongTo both, and these haveMany of each other Through the bridge entity. So yeah, the bridge entity can have the tuple id1 id2 as PK, but cannot have children entities