# Return additional fields from related model in StrongLoop

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

In a situation similar to this one, [Getting joined data from strongloop/loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560735/getting-joined-data-from-strongloop-loopback), where one has *Products* and product *Categories*, how does one return the *Category Name* rather than the id (foreign key) as the default response for */Products*?  I've been able to hide the id field but not return the name.  Thanks.

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have the relation `Product` hasOne `Category`, called `productCat`

With Node API

```
Product.find({
 include: {
    relation: 'productCat', // include the Category object
    scope: { // further filter the Category object
      fields: 'name', // only show category name
    }
  }
}, function(err, results) { /* ... */});
```

With REST API

```
GET api/Products?filter={"include":{"relation":"productCat","scope":{"fields":"name"}}}
```

Hope this helps (haven't tested it but it should work)